# Why ioremap allocated areas have such large aligment?

Tags: linux-kernel, ram, ioremap

I have a code that fails calling `ioremap()` for 4M region. Trying to debug the reason, I've found out that if you call `ioremap` it will try to allocate continuous addresses with a very large alignment (depending on the size of the area you want to allocate). The code that computes this alignment is in `__get_vm_area_node()` function (`mm/vmalloc.c`) and it looks like this:

```
if (flags & VM_IOREMAP) {
    int bit = fls(size);

    if (bit > IOREMAP_MAX_ORDER)
        bit = IOREMAP_MAX_ORDER;
    else if (bit < PAGE_SHIFT)
        bit = PAGE_SHIFT;

    align = 1ul << bit;
}
```

On ARM, `IOREMAP_MAX_ORDER` is defined as `23`. This means that in my case, `ioremap` needs not only 4M of continues addressing in `vmalloc` area but it also has to be aligned to 4M.

I wasn't able to find any information on why this alignment is needed. I even tried using git blame to see the commit that introduces this change but it seems the code is older than git history so I couldn't find anything.